# Catalog sales rule Magento 2

Tags: catalog-price-rules, sales

I have create a **custom module** that is overriding catalog sales rule module.

I have add some banner and text on those products which are in the sale. 
Now I  am confused that what happens when sales get expired? I actually want that when sale expires the banners and text should not be displayed on the product page.

If anyone has worked on catalog sales rule please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Below code is work for me

```
$catalogprice = $_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('catalog_rule_price')->getAmount()->getValue();
if($catalogprice) {
    // Show Banner
}
```

Comment: how do i show specific banner according to the rule?